ORA-29024: Certificate validation failure When Using in apex_web_service.make_rest_request or UTL_HTTP.REQUEST Oracle APEX (Autonomous Database)
I followed all the steps in this forum and let's say that from the autonomous sql developer it worked in these two ways:
ORA-29024: Certificate validation failure When Using UTL_HTTP.REQUEST in Autonomous Database
ORA-29024: Certificate validation failure - When using UTL_HTTP.REQUEST From SQL Developer Web/ Apex (Doc ID 2687222.1)
With this service, I still get the error:

https://www.datos.gov.co

SELECT UTL_HTTP.REQUEST('https://www.datos.gov.co') FROM dual;

ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1594
ORA-29024: Certificate validation failure
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 380
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1534
ORA-06512: at line 1
29273. 00000 - "HTTP request failed"
*Cause: The UTL_HTTP package failed to execute the HTTP request.
*Action: Use the GET_DETAILED_SQLERRM function to check the detailed error
message. Fix the error and retry the HTTP request.
Error at Line: 1 Column: 6


SELECT * FROM   dba_host_acls ORDER BY host;




"HOST"
"LOWER_PORT"
"UPPER_PORT"
"ACL"
"ACLID"
"ACL_OWNER"
"USE_DNS_PROXY"
"PRIVATE_TARGET"





"*"


"NETWORK_ACL_162E6"
0000000080002724
"SYS"
"N/A"
"NO"



"www.datos.gov.co"


"/sys/acls/httpg.xml"
0000000080002765
"SYS"
"N/A"
"NO"



"www.example.com"


"/sys/acls/httpa.xml"
0000000080002764
"SYS"
"N/A"
"NO"



"www.google.com"


"NETWORK_ACL_199F2E61DE81"
0000000080002760
"SYS"
"N/A"
"NO"





SELECT * FROM DBA_HOST_ACES;




"HOST"
"LOWER_PORT"
"UPPER_PORT"
"ACE_ORDER"
"START_DATE"
"END_DATE"
"GRANT_TYPE"
"INVERTED_PRINCIPAL"
"PRINCIPAL"
"PRINCIPAL_TYPE"
"PRIVILEGE"
"USE_DNS_PROXY"
"PRIVATE_TARGET"





"*"


2


"GRANT"
"NO"
"C##OMLREST2"
"DATABASE"
"RESOLVE"
"N/A"
"NO"



"*"


2


"GRANT"
"NO"
"C##OMLREST2"
"DATABASE"
"CONNECT"
"N/A"
"NO"



"*"


1


"GRANT"
"NO"
"GSMADMIN_INTERNAL"
"DATABASE"
"RESOLVE"
"N/A"
"NO"



"www.datos.gov.co"


1


"GRANT"
"NO"
"ADMIN"
"DATABASE"
"HTTP"
"N/A"
"NO"



"www.datos.gov.co"


1


"GRANT"
"NO"
"ADMIN"
"DATABASE"
"CONNECT"
"N/A"
"NO"



"www.datos.gov.co"


1


"GRANT"
"NO"
"ADMIN"
"DATABASE"
"RESOLVE"
"N/A"
"NO"



"www.datos.gov.co"


2


"GRANT"
"NO"
"APEX_230200"
"DATABASE"
"CONNECT"
"N/A"
"NO"



"www.datos.gov.co"


2


"GRANT"
"NO"
"APEX_230200"
"DATABASE"
"RESOLVE"
"N/A"
"NO"



"www.datos.gov.co"


2


"GRANT"
"NO"
"APEX_230200"
"DATABASE"
"HTTP"
"N/A"
"NO"



"www.example.com"


1


"GRANT"
"NO"
"ADMIN"
"DATABASE"
"RESOLVE"
"N/A"
"NO"



"www.example.com"


1


"GRANT"
"NO"
"ADMIN"
"DATABASE"
"CONNECT"
"N/A"
"NO"



"www.google.com"


1


"GRANT"
"NO"
"ADMIN"
"DATABASE"
"HTTP"
"N/A"
"NO"



"www.google.com"


2


"GRANT"
"NO"
"APEX_230200"
"DATABASE"
"HTTP"
"N/A"
"NO"



"www.google.com"


2


"GRANT"
"NO"
"APEX_230200"
"DATABASE"
"CONNECT"
"N/A"
"NO"



"www.google.com"


2


"GRANT"
"NO"
"APEX_230200"
"DATABASE"
"RESOLVE"
"N/A"
"NO"




But to the principal_name to APEX_APPLICATION.g_flow_schema_owner it doesn't work for me in Oracle APEX.
SELECT UTL_HTTP.REQUEST('https://www.google.com') FROM dual;
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed

It works

select apex_web_service.make_rest_request (
p_url => 'https://www.google.com',
p_http_method => 'GET'
) from dual;

Does not work

select apex_web_service.make_rest_request (
p_url => 'https://www.datos.gov.co',
p_http_method => 'GET'
) from dual;

ORA-29273: HTTP request failed

Regards

A Certificate error is different to network permissions. If it was related to ACL issues, you would get the following:
SQL> SELECT UTL_HTTP.REQUEST('https://www.datos.gov.co') FROM dual;
SELECT UTL_HTTP.REQUEST('https://www.datos.gov.co') FROM dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1620
ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 380
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1560
ORA-06512: at line 1

Certificates are related to the wallet entries to access a site via SSL.
First thing to try is this:
SELECT UTL_HTTP.REQUEST('https://www.datos.gov.co',wallet_path=>'system:') from dual;

which will use OS level certificate store. If that doesn't work, then this site is not using one of the typical certificate providers. That complicates things, and you'd need to check out
https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/autonomous-database-serverless/doc/external-calls-with-customer-managed-wallet.html#GUID-89B2A9C2-7567-451B-9150-04D3852C0DCB
for details on setting up your own wallet

Hi, I have tried using wallet_path=>'system:'  in two free autonomous database environments, but I am getting different errors: an ORA-24247 error in one and ORA-29024 in the other. I have reviewed the reference documentation and one of the requirements I do not meet is "Configure Network Access with Private Endpoints". Does this mean that it is not possible to access the web in a free environment?

The certificate for that web site needs to be added to the certificates used by ADB. We will do that.

@YasinB Thank you for your response. Could you please provide an approximate date when the certificate is expected to be added to ADB?

Probably in a week or two.
